# Can an Artificer Infusions or Armorer 's Arcane Armor be used with a College of Creation Bard's Performance of Creation?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, artificer, artificer-infusions

Can an Artificer's Infusions or Armorer's Arcane Armor be used  with a College of Creation Bard's Performance of Creation?

> [...] create one nonmagical item of your choice [...] the gp value of the item can't be more than 20 times your bard level, and the item must be Medium or smaller. The item glimmers softly, and a creature can faintly hear music when touching it. The created item disappears after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus. [...]

Now even though the item created via Performance of Creation has a duration, can you still Infuse it? If it's armor, can you make it your Arcane Armor? Does it still disappear after the duration or does it become a permanent item?

Comment: Is there a reason you believe it would become permanent?

Comment: Where did you get your quote for performance of creation? It does not match the official wording of the feature.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. Are you asking what happens when an artificer infuses an item that was created by this performance?

Comment: TM: I was paraphrasing the the ability. You constant point out my lack of skill with the English language so more than likely came out wrong. Naut: Yes as much as can it be done. As far as the Arcane Armor is concerned it has the clause "cant be removed against your will", I figure that would make it permanent as the item disappearing after the set duration is most defiantly my my choice.

Comment: I was confused because you put it in a quote block as though you were quoting something and did not specify that it was a paraphrase/summary.

Comment: In regards to the arcane armour, permanence is an interesting question due to the specific rules regarding it, not sure if such a case could extend to other infusions.

Comment: A direct quote would be **vastly** more useful. At the very least, we are definitely not making a paraphrase *look like* a quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes.

The College of Creation Bard's Performance of Creation ability states that they can create a non-magical item that lasts for a number of hours equal to their proficiency bonus; that is, it will last for between 2 and 6 hours, depending on the level of the Bard.

The Artificer's Infuse Item ability states the following:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item.

As a result, if the Bard uses their Performance of Creation ability at the end of a long rest, then an artificer can use one of their infusions on it. Similarly, the Armorer Artificer's Arcane Armor ability states the following:

> As an action, you can turn a suit of armor you are wearing into Arcane Armor, provided you have smith's tools in hand.

If the item that was created was a suit of armor and they're wearing it, then the Artificer can use their Arcane Armor ability to turn it into a suit of Arcane Armor.

However, neither of these abilities would extend the duration of the Performance of Creation, so they probably shouldn't. Arcane Armor can't be removed against your will, but it can be destroyed against your will. If it was meant to be invincible, then it would be spelled out as such in the rules. If someone casts Disintegrate at your Arcane Armor, it'll be destroyed unless it's a magic item.

Comment: @Akixkisu If it was meant to be invincible, then it would be spelled out as such in the rules. If someone casts Disintegrate at your Arcane Armor, it'll be destroyed unless it's a magic item.

Comment: Alternate phrasing: "Arcane Armor can't be removed against your will--but it _can_ cease to exist." It's not really being destroyed, per-say...it's just doesn't exist anymore. Nobody is removing it...it's just no longer a thing.

Comment: guilds: this makes sense. Thanks